# Как создать директорию для загрузки библиотек в R

Tags: r, библиотеки, загрузка

Я только учусь работать в R.
Как создать директорию для загрузки библиотек в R?
Instal Packeges требует установку в директорию С:/Users/...
Мне нужно создать свою. Где ее создавать, как и какой командой это сделать.[image: фото ошибки]

Comment: Я бы создавал, там, где нет кириллического в пути. Ну и это точно не то, что нужно синхронизировать (проще хранить список пакетов и заново его установить на другой машине -- это более безопасная стратегия).

Answer (score 0):

В install. packages() есть аргумент "lib", в нем новую директорию и указываете.

Например,install. packages("stringr", lib= "С:/Users/Lupaipupa/")

Соответственно, используя функцию "library", указываете в аргументе lib.loc указываете свою Новую директорию, если Вам нужна пакеты, которые лежат там.

Summary есть тут:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages

[https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/library#:~:text=library(help%20%3D%20somename)%20computes,are%20searched%20before%20the%20libraries](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/library#:%7E:text=library(help%20%3D%20somename)%20computes,are%20searched%20before%20the%20libraries).